# How to filter from both the main entity and the relation in typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

I have two entities named user and permission like this:

**User:**

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Authorized()
  @Field()
  @Column()
  @Index({
    unique: true,
  })
  email!: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  name!: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => Permission,
    permission => permission.users,
  )
  @JoinTable()
  @Field(type => [Permission])
  permissions: Permission[];
}
```

**Permission:**

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Permission {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  @Index({
    unique: true,
  })
  name!: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => User,
    user => user.permissions,
  )
  @Field(type => [User])
  users: User[];
}
```

Now what I need to do is to see whether the user identified by the email `user@example.com` have the permission identified by the name `readData`. I tried to do it in the following way but it did not work:

```js
const userWithPermission = await userRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('user.email = :email', { email: 'user@example.com' })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.permissions', 'permission')
      .where('permission.name = :name', { name: 'readData' })
      .execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const userWithPermission = await userRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where("(user.email = :email) AND (permission.name = :name)", {
    email: 'user@example.com',
    name: 'readData'
  })
  .leftJoinAndSelect("user.permissions", "permission")
  .execute();
```